# How to change webpage based on admin input

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

So I’m making a webpage for a friend, who doesn’t program. I’m trying to make a webpage where they can log in to an admin account on the site and pick one of three options from a menu. The dropdown needs to then change the main page to the color in the dropdown for everyone who visits it. Is there a way I could store it as a car in a JSON or something? Writing in JS, HTML, and CSS. Any help or ideas appreciated!

I have so far thought about trying to make a JSON file to store on the server and modify and read that as needed, but that seemed to be pretty tricky.

Comment: When the admin person picks an option the value of the option they pick (eg hexadecimal color value) needs to be persisted. A very common way to do that is to store the value in a database (I like using SQLite). Then the webpage that needs its color setting (that could be color of text or background) should use the value of the color from the database to create a style attribute in its HTML. In order to do this the HTML needs to be created by a server side programming language like python, PHP or node.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP in `retrieve.php` you would do `$colour = file_get_contents(‘colour.conf’); echo $colour;` and then in `set.php` you would do `file_put_contents(‘colour.conf’, addslashes($_GET[‘colour’]));` then finally in `colour.html` include a form `<form action=“set.php”><select name=“colour”><option value=“one”>One</option></form>`

I’ll explain a little more for you, firstly `retrieve.php` outputs the stored colour by simply reading from the conf file and outputting to the screen. Then `set.php` is writing changes to disk. You are right, there is no need for json. As with all user input sanitising with addslashes is always required. Finally, the .html file is for input to select a colour.

I hope this helped clear things up for you a bit.